# Is there a Riemann hypothesis for the Hasse-Weil zeta function, generally?

Tags: zeta-functions

What form does the Riemann hypothesis have for a global L-function?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15350) is a thread you might want to see...

Comment: @J.M., that's very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of the Hasse-Weil zeta function associated with a certain elliptic curve, which has CM.
  I believe that if the Riemann hypothesis is valid then the Riemann hypothesis for such a Hasse-Weil zeta function is valid. Thus, I think that this problem is as difficult as Riemann hypothesis.

---

I want to complement my statement. Suppose that the elliptic curve *E* has CM.

It is known that the L-series of *E* is the Hecke L-series. Thus, we can show that L(*E*, s) is a meromorphic function over the entire complex plane. Considering *Artin's conjecture*, it seems that L(*E*, s) has no poles.

Since L(*E*, s) is a meromorphic function, 1/L(*E*, s) is also a meromorphic function. The function 1/L(*E*, s) can't be *zero* because L(*E*, s) has no poles.

The Hasse-Weil zeta function is given as
           Z(s)Z(s-1)/ L(*E*, s),
where Z(s) is the Riemann zeta function. Therefore, if the Hasse-Weil zeta function has *zeros* then the all *zeros* are the *zeros* of Z(s)Z(s-1).

Comment: you can edit your other post and add that info to it...

Comment: This should have been an edit to your previous answer. Now, it would be best to edit one into the other.